# Web Services Discovery: Is UDDI the next UDDI?

Tags: web-services, soap, uddi

We are building a system that should integrate SOAP web services from different providers.

We want to allow providers to register web services.

It seems exactly the purpose of UDDI.

But according to its [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Description_Discovery_and_Integration) UDDI was never adopted widely and has fallen into disuse.

The question is: In favor of what? What is the current proper way of integrating a collection of web services registered by certain authorized providers?

If the answer is UDDI: Where can I find updated information on how to set up my own UDDI service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that "disuse" is more of a 'disuse' publicly on the internet, meaning that there are few publicly available instances of UDDI. A number of large organizations use UDDI behind firewalls.

There are many other alternatives, ebXML, WSO2, WS-Discovery, mDNS, jGroups and more. It all depends on your use case, network topology and who you want to share information with.

For setting up your own UDDI server...

http://juddi.apache.org

We also have a cloud instance available for anyone to use (although it needs maintenance)

disclaimer: I am the PMC for jUDDI